# bash script using scp to transfer a file searched for

Tags: linux, bash

I've not had much experience with bash at all.  The below script worked when I didn't use the find command and just scp straight from the file.  But I'm trying to find and transfer a file which has todays d/m/y appended and transfer only this one after finding it.

Currently gives the error 'file not found' also not sure how to use variables in this situation, as I'm a PHP coder.  Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

FILENAME = appendname_'.date +%d%m%Y;

spawn bash -c "scp 'find /www/reports/archives . -name 
$FILENAME.txt'    ftpdomain.com:/"

expect "password:"

send "pwaord\r"

expect "*\r"

expect "ok"
```

Comment: something wrong with your single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [`ssh-keygen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) and [install the key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) on your server, then you can use `scp` without having to provide a password through `expect`. To your question, you can use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (bash supports `$()` and ``), something like

```
spawn bash -c "scp $(find /www/reports/archives -name $FILENAME.txt)  
        ftpdomain.com:/"
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch   gives me an error 'no such variable while executing' even if I just use textfile.txt instead of a variable so doesn't like the $( )